# Break out of script if it takes too long

Tags: powershell

I am trying to dump a lot of data into a file but if it takes too long I want to come out of the dump. Is there a way to do this in PowerShell? I tried the below but noticed that the logic is incorrect and will not do what I need.

```
$time = get-date
do
{
    dir c:\ -Recurse | Set-Content .\outtext.txt
}
while ((Get-Date).AddSeconds(5) -le $time)
```

Comment: I'd suggest using a `Job` to do your task.  Posting an answer for ya.

Comment: You might want to look at this post: [Powershell Start Process, Wait with Timeout, Kill and Get Exit Code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36934083/5671993)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this example, it'll stop the job after a minute if it hasn't completed:

```
$Now = Get-Date

Start-Job -Name 'C' -ScriptBlock {
  Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\' -Recurse | Set-Content -Path '.\outtext.txt' } 

Try
{
    Do
    {
        If ((Get-Date).AddMinutes(-1) -gt $Now)
        {
            Stop-Job -Name 'C'
            Throw 'an error'
        }
    } While ((Get-Job -Name 'C').State -eq 'Running')

    $Output = Receive-Job -Name 'C'
}
Catch
{
    $_
}
```

Comment: I ran this and there is no output in the file and I get a weird error.

Comment: If there's no output file, then it ran over the timeout and threw an error if you copied my example verbatim.. @SekouMoore

Comment: I want the data to still be captured even if it fails out.

Comment: It is not outputting even if it is killed by the stop-job. It looks like the only way it will output is if the get-childItem completes. But if you are using Recurse and stop it with the stop-job it never populates the file.

Comment: I am sorry I just realized why am having this issue. It is the IDE I am using. I ran this in PowerShell ISE and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Great, upvote and tag this as an answer for future searchers @SekouMoore